# How to stream 2 objects into a Flux mapped from the same input Flux?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I have a `Flux<List<ProgressEvent>>` where `ProgressEvent` has a `String message` and a `double value`. I would like to generate a `Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>>` where I generate 2 `ServerSentEvent<String>` items in the target stream for 1 `List<ProgressEvent>` in the source stream.

For now I did something like this:

```
Flux<List<ProgressEvent>> source = ...

Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> target = source
    .map(events -> ServerSentEvent.<String>builder() ...)
    .mergeWith(source.map(events -> ServerSentEvent.<String>builder() ...))
```

But it feels a bit strange to read twice from the source stream. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is `flatMap` + `Flux.just`:

```
    Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> target = source.flatMap(events ->
            Flux.just(ServerSentEvent.<String>builder() ..., ServerSentEvent.<String>builder() ...)
    )
```